# about the software fl sudio 11

Tags: software-installation

I've replaced my windows XP for ubuntu because my xp would not work, and that i replaced XP for ubuntu and all my files have including FL studio 11.
FL studio was the main program ii used to remix songs and themes, one of my favorites.
the question: is there an FL studio 11 producer edition compatible for ubuntu that i can download and install again?? and then i can retrieve my things from image line
i've put this picture for it

[FL Studio 11 producer edition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lM1FJ.jpg)

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this](https://ubuntustudio.org/tour/audio/)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try a free alternative:

### LMMS

> LMMS is a free cross-platform software which allows you to produce music with your computer. This covers creating melodies and beats, synthesizing and mixing sounds and arranging samples. You can have fun with your MIDI keyboard and much more – all in a user-friendly and modern interface. Furthermore LMMS comes with many ready-to-use instrument and effect plugins, presets and samples.

### Features

- Song-Editor for composing songs
- A Beat+Bassline-Editor for creating beats and basslines
- An easy-to-use Piano-Roll for editing patterns and melodies
- An FX mixer with 64 FX channels and arbitrary number of effects allow unlimited mixing possibilities
- Many powerful instrument and effect plugins out of the box
- Full user-defined track-based automation and computer-controlled automation sources
- Compatible with many standards such as SoundFont2, VST(i), LADSPA, GUS Patches, and MIDI
- Import of MIDI files, Hydrogen project files and FL Studio ® project files

**Last release available from this PPA:** [ppa:irie/lmms](https://launchpad.net/~irie/+archive/lmms) . To install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:irie/lmms
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lmms
```

For some reasons, it didn't work you can download them from:

https://launchpad.net/~irie/+archive/ubuntu/lmms/+packages

Comment: ok, thanks could the link for the to downloading the installer?
it's not letting me download from ppa

Comment: @djdejawmaster, added install instructions